# can xargs separate parameters?

Tags: linux, shell, xargs

```
echo "'param 1' 'param 2'" | xargs -n2 -I@ echo [@] [@]
```

This command outputs:

> [param 1 param 2] [param 1 param 2]

However, I would like it to output:

> [param 1] [param 2]

Is there a way to do this with `xargs`?  I plan to use this with `-L1` so the solution would handle multiple lines as well as multiple arguments.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?  Are you trying to 'decorate' each filename argument before executing a command, and to treat them one pair of file names at a time?  I would normally write a script for `xargs` to run that does the job - it is far less painful than trying to contort `xargs` into doing what it does not want to do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For those who find this from a search, the accepted answer did not work for me.

```
echo "'param 1' 'param 2'" | xargs -n1 | xargs -I@ echo \[@\] \[@\]
```

produces:

```
[param 1] [param 1]
[param 2] [param 2]
```

which does not meet the requirements given by the original poster to have xargs read in multiple entities, separate them, and send them to a single command ("echo" in the OP) as separate parameters. **Xargs is not designed for this sort of task!**

The bash answer can work.

```
p=(`echo "param1 param2"`); echo [${p[0]}] [${p[1]}]
```

produces:

```
[param1] [param2]
```

but this solution does not work with more than one line.

A correct solution with bash for sending pairs of lines as arguments to a single command is:

```
(echo 'param 1'; echo 'param 2'; echo 'param 3'; echo 'param 4') | while read line1; read line2; do echo "[$line1] [$line2]"; done
```

produces:

```
[param 1] [param 2]
[param 3] [param 4]
```

The GNU Parallel answer does work, but GNU Parallel must be make'd and installed. (The version packaged with Ubuntu is not GNU Parallel.)

Comment: @wok, can you elaborate? How can you use xargs to produce what I have produced with bash and what is required by the OP?

Comment: Maybe see http://stackoverflow.com/a/19497860/376454 if you want to apply the same treatment to every line of a file.

Comment: I have tried again, and **for a file** on Linux, I **need** to use `xargs` as shown in my answer. With your answer only, there is no **line break** in the output, just `[param 1] [param 2] [param 3] [param 4]`. Apart from this detail, your answer is very good.

Comment: @wok, your answer proves that xargs alone is not sufficient to do what the OP requires, and you need a bash solution (like my answer) for yours to work. Please edit your first comment that says my answer is wrong.

Comment: I cannot edit it, but I can remove it. Anyway, your answer does not work without xargs for a .txt file.

Comment: @wok, Thanks. My answer is intended for the "multiple lines" case mentioned by the OP. Your answer is needed for a different case. I think they are both correct for their own purpose. I wrote my answer because I had a need to process pairs of lines from a .txt file at one time.

Answer (score 3):

```
echo "'param 1' 'param 2'" | xargs -n1 | xargs -I@ echo \[@\] \[@\]
```

(In my shell I need to escape `[]`, your mileage may vary).

Comment: How would I separate the first from the second? For example if I wanted to swap the order the 2 parameters?

Answer (score 1):

With GNU Parallel you can do:

```
(echo 'param 1'; echo 'param 2') | parallel -N2 echo '\[{1}] \[{2}]'
```

Watch the intro video to learn more: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpaiGYxkSuQ

Answer (score 1):

why stick xargs? bash could handle this well:

```
p=(`echo "param1 param2"`); echo ${p[0]} ${p[1]}
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15180418/376454), given one `echo`:

> param1 param2
>
> param 3 param4

The following pipe:

```
... | while read line1; read line2; do echo "[$line1] [$line2]"; done
```

produces:

```
[param1] [param2]
[param3] [param4]
```

If you have a file `myFile.txt` containing many lines with two parameters on each, use the following strategy based on `xargs` in order to reuse the arguments as `$f` and `$g`:

```
cat myFile.txt | xargs -n1 | while read f; read g; do echo $f $g; done
```